# How to publish a value when a button is clicked?

Tags: java, android

Currently, the value is in an `editText`, and when the button is clicked, the value is published to a server. But how do I get rid of that `editText` and store that value in the button, so I do not need the `editText`? This method publishes the value of 32 when the button is pressed from the `editText`.

```
private void publishValue() {
    try {

        final MqttTopic myTopic = mqttClient.getTopic(TOPIC_VALUE);

        final int topicNumber = 32;

        EditText theTopic = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTopicValue);



        final String topic = theTopic.getText().toString();

        myTopic.publish(new MqttMessage(topic.getBytes()));

        System.out.println("Published data. Topic: " + myTopic.getTopic() + "  Message: " + topic);

    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if all you are trying to do is change the Button text to the EditText, then hide the EditText. The code for you is below.

So in the java code of your view, you probably want to have you UI controls as private variables. Then set an onClickListener for your button.

That "public void OnClick(view V)" is the void that will fire on when that button is clicked.

```
    editText = findViewById(R.id.textEdit);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            topic = editText.getText().toString();
            editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            button.setText(topic);
        }
    });
```